# Deleting feature

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I'm deleting a feature from a shapefile with this code:

```
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspaceFactory.openFromFile("C:/Users/me/Desktop", 0);
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass("sondage");
IWorkspaceEdit wse=(IWorkspaceEdit)featureWorkspace;
IQueryFilter qf=new QueryFilter();
String s="SALB 01";
qf.setWhereClause("n_sondage='"+s+"'");
IFeatureCursor pFeatureCursor = featureClass.search(qf, false);                 
int id=pFeatureCursor.nextFeature().getOID();
wse.startEditing(false);
wse.startEditOperation();
IFeature feat=featureClass.getFeature(id);
feat.delete();
wse.stopEditOperation();
wse.stopEditing(true);
```

It works, but when I called this function in another class in the same project, the feature is not deleted and the shape couldn't be drawn any more.

Comment: Did you consider using [ITable.DeleteSearchedRows](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#itable_deletesearchedrows.htm)?

Comment: No i've worked just with features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use an update cursor and not a search cursor. You can replace the table/row by featureclass/feature from my example.

```c#
ICursor cur = table.Update(queryFilter, false);
if (cur != null)
{
    IRow row = cur.NextRow();
    if (row != null)
    {
        while (row != null)
        {
            row.Delete();
            row = cur.NextRow();
        }                             
    }
}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cur);
```

Note: Please keep in mind to handle when no features or multiple features are returned in the cursor.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works, i think the problem is that i wasn't using the releaseComObject.

Comment: Why did you "ReleaseComObject"?

Comment: since you are using "while" loop  "if (row != null)" is not necessary. Thanks for tje solution, though :)